# Problem Parsing Malformed JSON dataset in Python

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I am having difficulty creating a panda dataframe from an intentionally malformed JSON data set. The difficulty I am having is that dirtyjson only seems to be parsing and writing one entry to the outfile as opposed to the whole JSON file:

```
# load json files into python
with open ('neither.json') as neither:    

neither_data = dirtyjson.load(neither)

neither_parsed = json.dumps(neither_data)

with open ('json_file_neither','w') as outfile:

json.dump(neither_data, outfile)
```

If anyone could point out how to rectify this problem or if anyone could suggest a better way than dityjson to clean the malformed JSON it would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Can we see an example of what the JSON file looks like?

Comment: May I ask why is the JSON malformed on purpose? What are the expected *malformations*?

Comment: Looking at the JSON at the end of each entry it has "}{" which shouldn't be there and a line: "is_quote_status": false which is creating a parse error. This is the case for every entry

Comment: The project is for a Data Wrangling class and the lecturer informed me that the JSON was purposefully malformed so that we would have to clean it

Comment: correction* i would like to remove "{" and add a comma that is missing after "is_quote_status":false